# Python CGI Issues

Tags: python, cgi

I am building a simple web app (posted part of it yesterday) but I am struggling with a portion:

1) Request a text file to upload
2) Save the uploaded file to a directory

I am using python and cgi for this. cgi is working as confirmed with a simple test.cgi file.

Here is my current code for request_input.cgi:

```
    #!/usr/bin/python
    import cgi
    print "Content-type: text/html\r\n\r\n"
    print '<html>'
    print '<body>'
    print '<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="save_input.cgi" method="post">'
    print '<p>File: <input type="file" name="filename" /></p>'
    print '<p>input type="submit" value="Upload" /></p>'
    print '</form>'
    print '</body>'
    print '</html>'
```

Now when I tail the apache error log I get the following errors:
"(2)No such file or directory: exec of '/var/www/ipcheck/request_input.cgi' failed, referer: [http://192.168.3.77/ipcheck/?C=M;O=A]"
"Premature end of script headers: request_input.cgi, referer [http://192.168.3.77/ipcheck/?C=M;O=A]"

Any help would be awesome! Thanks a lot

Comment: Sorry, just to clarify, the issue is when I attempt to run the request_input.cgi script on the web server, and the output are the Apache errors.

Comment: Are permissions on save_input.cgi (and where it's being saved) set correctly?

Comment: yes, I have a test file in the same location called test.cgi which works fine, same permissions. 755

Comment: did you write this on Windows?  if you have `\r` at the end of the first line, the system will try to run the executable `/usr/bin/python\r` which doesn't exist.

Comment: I did actually, then moved it over to my linux system for testing as that is where it should be hosted. If I modify to "Content-type: text/html\n\n" that may resolve?

Comment: no, no, the problem is that a _literal_ carriage return character is at the end of the first line.  your editor may support dos-style line endings, but the linux kernel doesn't.  `xxd request_input.cgi` will show you the literal bytes as a hex dump.  configure your editor to save with unix line endings, or use `dos2unix` to convert what you've got.

Answer (score 0):

dos2unix resolved issue. Built in windows, moved to linux. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

I simply copied all of the code in the file, opened a new python window, pasted the code into it and saved it under the same name (to overwrite the old file). Hope this helps!